# How to add basic authentication to wsdl file/soap api?

Tags: xml, api, authentication, soap, wsdl

I am new to soap APIs and I wanted to ask if there is the possibility to add basic authentication (username & password) to an existing .wsdl file? The question involves the xml elements that will be needed and not any code at all.

Thank you all in advance

Comment: that depends on where you host your service? if you host it in a webserver environment you need to configure that to accept basic authentication. if you host it as a windows service you need to specify it in the service config. The username/pw will be part of the http request and not a part of the actual message that you are sending.

Comment: @martijn the service will probably be hosted in a webserver environment as you said. So from what i understand, the right(maybe the only?) way is to configure the webserver to enforce the basic authentication policy meaning that the solution is not as simple as adding the appropriate xml elements?